# Word macros not running correctly when opened from PowerPoint action button

Tags: vba, ms-word, powerpoint

I have a Word template (suggestion from) which includes an autonew macro to insert a reference number at a book mark and an action button (Submit)which saves the resulting document with the reference number as part of the file name and closes Word. This works perfectly well when opening the template via Windows Explorer.

We also have a PowerPoint show with action settings hyperlinking to various documents. The link will open the above template OK but does not insert the reference number. Also when the 'submit' button is hit, the file saves as another template with the reference number included.

I am not sure if the issue is Word or PowerPoint-related. The code for the Word template is

```
Sub AutoNew()

REF = System.PrivateProfileString("L:\Local\Lab\Section - Support Services\Health and Safety\H&S Suggestions\Settings.Txt", _
        "MacroSettings", "REF")

If REF = "" Then
    REF = 1
Else
    REF = REF + 1
End If

System.PrivateProfileString("L:\Local\Lab\Section - Support Services\Health and Safety\H&S Suggestions\Settings.Txt", "MacroSettings", _
        "REF") = REF

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("REF").Range.InsertBefore Format(REF, "000#")


End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

REF = System.PrivateProfileString("L:\Local\Lab\Section - Support Services\Health and Safety\H&S Suggestions\Settings.Txt", _
        "MacroSettings", "REF")

ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:="L:\Local\Lab\Section - Support Services\Health and Safety\H&S Suggestions\Suggestion " & Format(REF, "000#.doc")
Application.Quit

End Sub
```

Any help or pointers would be appreciated as if it works I'd like to use for various other templates.

Answer (score 0):

From the description, it's kind of hard to get an accurate idea of what's happening, but it SOUNDS like the the AUTONEW just might not get run in that particular combination.

You could verify this by using some logging or MSGBOX calls to see exactly what macros are being run, when.

Check the docs on Autonew here

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/211659

Sounds like it won't run if the macro is saved in Normal, which doesn't sound like the case here but it's worth noting.

You might also consider using the AutoOpen macro and checking other elements to make sure this is a brand new doc instead of one that's already been saved (like checking the content of the Document.Fullname property).

Comment: Thanks after looking into logging etc I worked out the problem lies in the powerpoint macros used to open the word document.

Comment: Thanks after looking into logging etc I worked out the problem lies in the powerpoint macros used to open the word document. The first part is actually opening the template itself rather than a document based on it (bascially its opening the template for editing) . I just need to work out what other code is needed to create the document. Hopefully the second problem is related because its looking for a reference number that isn't there.

Comment: Ah, yes, didn't event think about that because I almost never use that argument. Start word like winword.exe /t{templatefilename} to create a new document based on the named template. That should start firing the AUTONEW macro properly.